# TypeScript interfaces not enforcing properties when an object is assigned

Tags: typescript

I'm having a hard time making sense of TypeScript's rules for interfaces. I understand that the following block of code throws an error because the `id` property isn't defined in the interface:

```js
interface Person {
   name: string;
}

let person: Person = { name: 'Jack', id: 209 }
```

But why does TypeScript **not** throw an error if I try to add the `id` property by assigning another object? Like this for instance:

```js
const samePerson = { name: 'Jack', id: 209 };
person = samePerson;
```

The `person` object ends up getting the `id` property, even though it isn't defined in the interface.

Comment: Because TS implements the structural typing type system: which allows that kind of assignment.

Comment: Think about interfaces as a minimum requirements, not maximum

Answer (score 3):

### Object types are generally open and extendible, and allow extra properties...

Object types in TypeScript are generally open and extendible.  An object is a `Person` if and only if it has a `name` property of type `string`.  Such an object may turn out to have additional properties, but it's still a `Person`.  This is very useful and allows interface extensions to form type hierarchies:

```
interface AgedPerson extends Person {
  age: number;
}

const agedPerson: AgedPerson = { name: "Alice", age: 35 };
const stillAPerson: Person = agedPerson; // okay
```

And because TypeScript has a [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), you don't actually have to declare an interface for `AgedPerson` for it to be seen as a subtype of `Person`:

```
const undeclaredButStillAgedPerson = { name: "Bob", age: 40 };
const andStillAPersonToo: Person = undeclaredButStillAgedPerson; // okay
```

Here `undeclaredButStillAgedPerson` has a type of `{name: string, age: number}`, equivalent to `AgedPerson`, and the subsequent assignment to a `Person` works for the same reason.

---

Even though open/extendible typing is useful, it can be confusing and is sometimes not desired.  There is a longstanding open request at [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) for TypeScript to support so-called *exact* types, where something like `Exact<Person>` would *only* be allowed to have a `name` property and nothing else.  An `AgedPerson` would be a `Person` but not an `Exact<Person>`.  There is currently no direct support for such exact types.

---

### ...but *object literals* do undergo excess property checking.

Jumping back: object types in TypeScript are *generally* open.  But there is one situation where an object will be treated as if its type were exact.  And this is when you assign an [*object literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to a variable or pass it as an argument.

Object literals get special treatment and undergo [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) when first assigned to a variable or passed as a function argument. If the object literal has properties not known to exist in the expected type, there's an error.  Like this:

```
let person: Person = { name: 'Jack', id: 209 }; // error!
// ------------------------------->  ~~~~~~~
// Object literal may only specify known properties, 
// and 'id' does not exist in type 'Person'.
```

Even though `{name: "Jack", id: 209}` *is* a `Person` by the original definition, it's not an `Exact<Person>`, and so we get an error.  Please note that the error specifically mentions "object literals".

---

Contrast this to the following, where there is no error:

```
const samePerson = { name: 'Jack', id: 209 }; // okay
person = samePerson; // okay
```

The assignment of the object literal to `samePerson` is not in error because `samePerson`'s type is *inferred* to be of the type

```
/* const samePerson: {
    name: string;
    id: number;
} */
```

and there's no excess property there.  The subsequent assignment of `samePerson` to `person` also succeeds, because `samePerson` is not an object literal, and therefore excess property checking does not apply.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzEC+xxoksiKAQSYQAJuijZcEAB6QQIjGkw58xUnGG0QAVwoAjaGyKcixBDnrINo8ZNpCby3AF58ZSjWQAiAQBtgSF4ANFaayADMAKzI7EbmIJb0wL6+ArY4tOkuoY4SOCzIAPSFyFgA1nAAnlxE8Zba8hAIvnBQogBC2mAAymDJqcJiTsiueO5UtF7tWHrBObQALAAMMXEWYFbyvf1pTgAqWFiZw64NIk0tbSKdPX0pDkN5IAXFpRXVpp-EvhAbAA5OY5PEZucgTZAAcgAUogyhCQsARLQAExLACcqyKJWgUCwUAAhMRXgBaUlk8kUylUskAPlIAD9GUz6USSgB5PQAKyaG38vDgvmQFCqpRAvkqdABCGAMAlZRAWAA7rg-riAVA+hAMCE4PJIYiIcgRFgtWQsBsZMBLKBkGBKgDIVkIQA6Gp1DYYDxZEFjMGeaGw+HIREo9GrIkAKmQ7roXsBqhIpHGnnojBArDUSZDZF0BigRnYyAjhWI6skIM9VCyRiAA)

Comment: But if `{ name: 'Jack', id: 209 }` is assigned to `samePerson`, doesn't that mean that the variable holds an object literal?

Comment: An object [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) is *notation*, with curly braces and colons and stuff in it.  An object literal *refers* to an object, but it is not the object itself.  The variable `samePerson` holds a reference the object referred to by the object literal, but it does not hold that object literal (there are no actual curly braces in `samePerson` anywhere).  If this is too confusing, then let's say that an object literal is only checked for excess properties when it's "fresh", but once it is used it loses its freshness and is not checked.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, this is fixed in typescript 4.9 with satisfies operator
so if you create type like this

```
type User = {
    name: string
    age: number
}

const user = { name: 'John Doe', age: 22 } satisfies User
```

it won't allow other properties in this object if you try to add it it will give you error

Answer (score 1):

**Let's try and understand**

An interface is a syntactical contract that an entity should conform to.

Interfaces define properties, methods, and events, which are the members of the interface. Interfaces contain only the declaration of the members. It is the responsibility of the deriving class to define the members. It often helps in providing a standard structure that the deriving classes would follow

In addition, we can implement multiple interfaces so that implementer can have more than what one interface defines.

While classes must adhere to what's in the contract, it can also have it's own additional implementation (This is mostly true with many languages)

Coming to Typescript, like @zerkms said

> Type compatibility in TypeScript is based on structural subtyping.
> Structural typing is a way of relating types based solely on their
> members.

The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that x is compatible with y if y has at least the same members as x. For Example:

```
interface Pet {
  name: string;
}
let pet: Pet;
// dog's inferred type is { name: string; owner: string; }
let dog = { name: "Lassie", owner: "Rudd Weatherwax" };
pet = dog;
```

To check whether dog can be assigned to pet, the compiler checks each property of pet to find a corresponding compatible property in dog. In this case, dog must have a member called name that is a string. It does, so the assignment is allowed.

Ref: [type-compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

Comment: This answer explains why `const samePerson = { name: 'Jack', id: 209 }; person = samePerson;` succeeds, but does not explain why `let person: Person = { name: 'Jack', id: 209 }` fails.

Comment: I think I clearly missed to explain that part. However you explained it well. As you mentioned first example is converting/assigning and as long as things match it will work. However, in the second part we are clearly declaring person of type Person and assigning values it would result in error.